# What determines which services svchost.exe hosts?

Tags: windows, services, windows-services, svchost

When viewing processes under Process Explorer, there is *services.exe*, which has several *svchost.exe* subprocesses. Each of these hosts one or more services. However, selection of services in single process seems completely random.

How does the process select which services it hosts? Can this be affected somehow?

I can't find any controls for this in *services.msc*.

I would want to force some services into their own processes, separate from others.

Answer (score 3):

There is a database in the Registry to control how services are loaded. This is the Service Control Manager database.

The Service Control Manager runs services.exe. Services are defined in the Registry under HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services.
The `Type` value of the service's entry specifies if it is loaded in its own process or in a process that hosts multiple services.

When the SCM decides to start a service, it calls ScStartService. ScStartService determines the name of the file that runs the service's process by reading the `ImagePath` value from the service's Registry key. The `ImagePath` value also contains the name of the group. It then examines the `Type` value. A value of 0x20 indicates a shared process.

To answer your question about how to make a service run in its own process, use the `sc config` command.

Example: `sc config wuauserv type= own`  The space after = is required.

[Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990290.aspx)

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682544(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You won't find *controls* in services.msc, but each service will be started under a particular user/service account which has particular rights depending on the requirements of the service.

The column "Log On As" in the services control panel will show you what service account is used for particular services. You'll note that each `svchost.exe` in task manager appears to be from a different user account.

It is these accounts that will determine which `svchost.exe` is hosting each service.

---

Technically there are controls to change what `svchost.exe` is hosting a particular service as you can change the user that the service logs on as in the "Log On" tab of the service properties. I would not advise changing them though as you could end up with services starting up in the wrong order or without the rights that they require.

Comment: I see. Assuming I take the risk, I would have to create completely new service user. But that is probably worthy of another SU question.

Comment: Yes. I've seen some programs do exactly that and when combined with filesystem permissions can make a service that can be effectively given a folder area where only that service can work. I'd agree that the creation of services sounds like a new question, but I also suspect we might already have a question detailing that.